# Why is my EPS red?

Tags: the-monolith

For some reason my total EPS readout has turned red, and is much lower than it should be? What's going on, and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your monolith.  The Beast has attached a leech to it, and is sucking away your evolution points.  You need to attack the leech manually and destroy it.  That will set your EPS back to the correct value.

Comment: Just downloaded the game because of this question and came across the same problem so thank you :)